# PHP - while inside while in table

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I have a table that I want to assign a staff member to for each row. I want a dropdown on the last column with all the staff members so I can assign a staff member by clicking their username in the dropdown.

I'm trying to do a while loop inside a while loop but am getting an error.

***This is my current code:***

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped js-dataTable-full table-header-bg">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Actions</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Service</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Date Ordered</th>
        <th>Account Email</th>
        <th>Account Password</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Assign to staff</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
        <?php
        $clients_result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM boosting_orders ORDER BY id ASC");
        $query = mysqli_query( $con, "SELECT * FROM users" );
        if(mysqli_num_rows($clients_result) > 0) {
        while($payment_row = mysqli_fetch_array($clients_result)) {

        echo '                  
        <tr id="no_enter">
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-default" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Edit Order" href="orders_admin?action=edit&identification='.$payment_row['id'].'"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-default" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Remove Order" href="orders_admin?action=delete&identification='.$payment_row['id'].'"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                '.$payment_row['users_name'].'
            </td>
            <td>
                '.$payment_row['service'].'
            </td>
            <td>
                $'.$payment_row['price'].'
            </td>
            <td>
                '.$payment_row['date_ordered'].'
            </td>
            <td>
                '.$payment_row['email'].'
            </td>
            <td>
                '.$payment_row['password'].'
            </td>
            <td>
                '.($payment_row['status'] == 'Completed' ? '<span class="label label-success" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Your account has successfully been boosted">Completed</span>' : '<span class="label label-info" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="This order is either still pending or corrupt">Pending</span>').'
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="assign_staff" class="form-control">
                    '. while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { .'
                        <option value="'.$row['username'].'">'.$row['username'].'</option>
                    '. } .'
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        ';
        } } else {  } ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: You can't use while inside echo

Comment: _but am getting an error._ What error?

Comment: Why is your entire table row in one echo? :/

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton the error is : `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE)`

Comment: Yes, it's because of what @DimitrisFilippou said. You are doing PHP way wrong, you should either have many many echo statements, or switch out of PHP for HTML (Which is recommended)

Comment: You need to go back to php 101. This is a bad start to coding. The code above is filled with bad practices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't concatenate string with while syntax,
the code in the last `<td>` should be:

```
echo '<select name="assign_staff" class="form-control">';
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                     echo '<option value="' . $row['username'] . '">' . $row['username'] . '</option>';
                     }
                 echo '</select>
```